# Form is not disposing after closing it

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have windows form application in this I used Infragistics controls. I analyze the memory process after opening the form memory usage goes 27 MB but after closing it memory should release but it not working. While closing I called Dispose method also.

[image: Close button click.]

[image: After opening the form memory usage]

[image: After closing the form memory usage]

Comment: `Form is not disposing after closing it` It definitely is being disposed (since you called `Close` and `Dispose`). Now, that is a separate issue to whether it is GCed. To help with that, we'll need to see a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: How much you've waited? By calling dispose it doesn't mean memory will release instantly, it will release when GC will decide so.

Comment: Is your project really called `test`? Do you get the same behaviour when running the Release build?

Comment: GC does not work this way. `From.Dispose()/Close()` only released unmanaged resources like handle, while managed resource (memory) is collected by GC. And GC only triggers when it _feels_ it is time to collect garbage, just calling `Form.Close()` does not trigger a GC collection. You have to call `GC.Collect()` explicitly to see a difference.

Comment: Apart from everything else that has been said, try minimising your app and you'll probably see a drop in memory usage due to activation of the GC.

Comment: I have often found that event handlers are often the cause of forms or objects not being GCed when you think they should be.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts.

- Don't use *Task Manager* to diagnose memory problems. Use a memory profiler. .Net manages its memory in a way which is not entirely obvious and *Task Manager* gives false assumptions about that nature of this.
- Just because you dispose something, it doesn't mean the garbage collector is going to race to clean up and aggressively give memory back to the operating system, it will do it when it feels like it based on memory pressure and heuristics .
- If you create a form (and its modal) you might as well just put it in a `using` statement, then you have peace-of-mind that you are doing everything correctly

---

**Additional Resources**

[Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)